# No virtualenv implementation for PythonInfo

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm having virtualenv implementation error. I know python2.7 is old, but still need.
Does anyone have solution?

No virtualenv implementation for PythonInfo({'base_exec_prefix': None, 'system_stdlib': u'/usr/lib/python2.7', 'has_venv': False, 'prefix': u'/usr', 'stdout_encoding': u'UTF-8', 'executable': '/usr/bin/python2.7', 'implementation': u'CPython', 'exec_prefix': u'/usr', 'platform': u'linux2', 'version': u'2.7.16 (default, Feb 10 2020, 18:54:57) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]', 'sysconfig_paths': {u'platstdlib': u'{platbase}/lib64/python{py_version_short}', u'platlib': u'{platbase}/local/lib64/python{py_version_short}/site-packages', u'purelib': u'{base}/local/lib/python{py_version_short}/site-packages', u'stdlib': u'{base}/lib/python{py_version_short}', u'scripts': u'{base}/local/bin', u'include': u'{base}/local/include/python{py_version_short}', u'data': u'{base}/local'}, 'base_prefix': None, 'file_system_encoding': u'UTF-8', 'version_info': VersionInfo(major=2, minor=7, micro=16, releaselevel=u'final', serial=0), 'sysconfig_vars': {u'base': u'/usr', u'platbase': u'/usr', u'PYTHONFRAMEWORK': u'', u'py_version_short': u'2.7'}, 'path': [u'/usr/local/bin', u'/usr/lib/python27.zip', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', u'/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', u'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages', u'/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'], 'max_size': 9223372036854775807, 'real_prefix': None, 'distutils_install': {u'purelib': u'lib/python2.7/dist-packages', u'headers': u'include/python2.7/UNKNOWN', u'platlib': u'lib64/python2.7/dist-packages', u'data': u'', u'scripts': u'bin'}, 'architecture': 64, 'original_executable': u'/usr/bin/python2.7', 'os': u'posix', 'system_executable': u'/usr/bin/python2.7'})

Comment: What you have shown is a blob of metadata. Can you clarify how this error occurred? What command did you execute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have Virtualenv 20. Try installing an older version of Virtualenv instead.

```
pip install -U 'virtualenv<20.0'
```

Comment: Worked for me on my new M1 Max on Monterey. AFAIU we need an older version of virtualenv because we'are using older python (2.7.x)

Comment: @sscarduzio Yep. You shouldn't be using Python 2 at all, though.

Comment: Using this solution, I then get this error when creating the Venv: ```ERROR: The executable /Users/mike/Envs/scigraph-explorer-schema-py2/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/mike/Envs' (should be u'/Users/mike/Envs/scigraph-explorer-schema-py2')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable```